# Selectively allow SOAP on one or more messages in ServiceStack

Tags: soap, servicestack

We are currently using ServiceStack for our web api which is 99% REST/JSON however we have one new message that we need to allow a SOAP endpoint for. (*The client is an older BizTalk server and SOAP 12 is required.*) We want to prevent SOAP on everything else but this one message. Is there a way to enable the SOAP Feature on a single message or service? What are the scopes to which SOAP can be specified?

In our AppHost Configure() we have removed the Features we want to disallow with `EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove( Feature.Csv | Feature.Html | Feature.Jsv | Feature.Soap )` however this removes our ability to expose the SOAP12 WSDL. On the flip-side, not removing `Feature.Soap` enables SOAP for all POST messages which we need to prevent.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question.
ServiceStack has provided a way to specify what endpoint channels are available and to whom using the `ServiceStack.ServiceHost.RestrictAttribute` (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Security). In order to limit the visibility of my message to only SOAP12:

```
//Request DTO
[DataContract(Namespace = Namespaces.Messages.NS_2013_01 )]
[Restrict(EndpointAttributes.Soap12 )]
public class Hello
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The visibility in my metadata is restricted appropriately:
[image]